# how can we set the frame location for the required jsp page..?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

i want to know how can we set the location for a frame.suppose i have two frames, frame_top and frame_bottom, now i have some logic in frame_top. Result should be displayed in bottom_frame.

```
              _________
             |    top  |
             |   frame |
             -----------
             |   bottom|
             |   frmae |
             -----------
```

generally  a action in a form specify the page to be loaded after submitting a form, here we can set frame on which the respective result page should come.

```
         like :
        <from action=go_bottom.jsp target="bottom_frame" method=post >
```

similarly  i want to do using fallow way
              code: //java script in top frame

```
        function open1(){
         document.form2.action="go_bottom.jsp"; //here i want to set the frame location
         document.f0rm2.submit();
         }
```

so the document.form2.action will submit the form and send the results into respective page.
how can i set the frame_bottom here.?

Comment: Please provide more details, are you using any frameworks, etc..? What exactly do you want to get in the bottom.jsp? Thanks

Comment: Dropout, see i have give some more description. give some solution.

Comment: Setting the action to the same page and passing the results in POST for example doesn't work for you?

Comment: You really shouldn't use frames on any new development.